# Codeigniter 404 not found error when accessing anything inside application folder

Tags: codeigniter, server, hosting

I am having a problem after hosting my codeIgniter project on live shared hosting server.
Before doing that, I changed few things on my local server.

.htaccess file-

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

.config.php inside config folder-

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

to let it work properly on my local server without writing index.php in URL. But when I moved it to live server, I changed base_url as-

```
http://crm.sachinartani.com
```

as I am hosting it on my subdomain, but it always output-

```
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.
```

I watched all videos on YouTube and traversed all questions of StackOverflow but none of the solutions helped me. There is a folder aside application folder namely *inc* which contains CSS and JS files I am using in my project. I am able to access those files by URL as - http://crm.sachinartani.com/inc but I cannot access any controllers and views like this.